# Loading shared object to specific processes in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, kernel-module, dynamic-library

I want to load a shared object to certain processes, there are certain conditions that are required:

- Loading to only specific processes and not all of them;
- It has to be done before the process code starts executing;
- The processes are not mine.

What are the available ways to support this functionality on Linux?

Can it be accomplished with "/etc/ld.so.preload" or "LD_PRELOAD=/my/lib.so"? Is a kernel module needed for this?

Comment: If you have conflicting shared libraries, use containers to separate them.

Comment: hi @stark, thanks, however it's not about conflicts, I want to control certain functionality so containers are irrelevant in my case

Comment: There is no way to easily do what you want under Linux. If you do not have control over what starts the process (and how), but you need to have a shared object preloaded into it before the process starts executing its own code, you can't do much from another process. The only way I can think of doing this is replacing the dynamic loader of the system with a custom version created by you.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thanks, I will check about replacing the dynamic loader.
would it be possible to control the behavior with a kernel module?

Comment: @ALsec AFAIK not with a kernel module because the kernel ELF loader is built-in into the kernel, so adding a kernel module wouldn't do much as it wouldn't be able to "replace" or "control" the loader... you could use it to attach some hooks but that'd be pretty clumsy.

Comment: thanks @MarcoBonelli I'll check /etc/ld.so.preload as you & Rachid suggested below and search for other avenues

Answer (score 1):

**LD_PRELOAD** could be used to load a specific generic tiny library which on its side will load any additional library the process needs with `dlopen()` service. Typically, applications able to load plugins, look into a specific directory and call `dlopen()` for all the library files found into it.
You need to define an entry point in the  generic library which will be triggered at loading time. With `gcc`you can define this entry point with a [constructor attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) lib_initialize(void);

void lib_initialize(void)
{
  // Look into a specific directory to see if there are libs to
  // load with dlopen()
}
```

This mechanism does not need any specific kernel module.

If **LD_PRELOAD** environment variable has too much limitations for the OP's use case, the libraries (or at least the tiny generic library discussed above) can be put in */etc/ld.so.preload*. Look at the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) of ld.so, section FILES.

Comment: thanks @Rachid K.
I'm unclear on how it can be used when I'm not the one who starts the target processes... if I hold off execution in lib_initialize(), e.g. by waiting on a file/socket, will it delay execution until the function returns or continue in another thread? appreciated!

Comment: I updated the answer to discuss about /etc/ld.so.preload mechanism.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting, I forgot about that system wide file. @ALsec it could be a good solution for you.